# Rails routing issue: Unwanted route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a Ruby on Rails project.  In my config/routes.rb, I have the following setup:

```
scope module: :comments do
  resources :tasks do
    resources :comments, only: %i[index]
  end
end
```

This creates the route that I want in `rake routes`:

```
v1_task_comments GET /v1/tasks/:task_id/comments(.:format)  v1/comments/comments#index
```

but it also creates the following route, which is wrong and which I don't want:

```
v1_tasks GET /v1/tasks(.:format)  v1/comments/tasks#index
```

How do I create the first route without generating the second?

Comment: Trick of the day: you can add `only` option, like the following: `resources :tasks, only: [] do` to only declare zero REST route for the `task` resource.

Comment: I just discovered this myself, except that I used `only: :none` which works and is more understandable, I feel.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Today I learned! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `only` option of `resources` routes helper:

```
resources :tasks, only: :none do
  # ...
end
```